# filter_input и ассоциативный массив

Tags: php, post

Умные дяди сказали получать POST(и GET) с помощью

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ИМЯ_ПЕРЕМЕННОЙ')
```

Если я передаю через POST ассоциативный массив, например

```
[sys] => Array
    (
        [page] => page_name
        [id] => page_id
    )
```

Запрос filter_input(INPUT_POST, '[sys]page') у меня не сработал, не могу понять, как это прочитать с помощью filter_input?

Comment: Не http://php.net/manual/ru/function.filter-input.php#115960?

Comment: спасибо, который раз убеждаюсь, что нужно подтягивать язык!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$var = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'var', FILTER_DEFAULT , FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
```